# MySite and MyProfile links missing in SharePoint 2010 for some users

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint

Some users in SharePoint 2010 don't have links in the upper right hand drop down menu for MySite or MyProfile.

In Central Admin I have MySite set to allow Read and Create for All Users (Windows) and All Authenticated Users. All of the users, including the ones missing the links are able to login and access most other SharePoint content and resources. I am able to view the MySite and Profile pages of the users missing the links in the menu.

I'm guessing that something is security trimming the drop down menu for some users. I just can't find anything that stands out outside of the UserProfile Service Application and MySite configuration that I've already done.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out http://www.paulgrimley.com/2010/07/my-site-and-my-profile-missing-from.html

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!!! I'll give this a shot. I could not find anything anywhere about this and you're the only person that replied in any of the tech sites I've asked on.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog on this actually, but my blog is about how to hide them, not how to make them appear, but the reverse works in this scenario.

Basically, there is a Farm feature called "SocialRibbonControl".  That farm feature is what adds those links to the welcome control.  So even if everything http://www.paulgrimley.com/2010/07/my-site-and-my-profile-missing-from.html says checked out, they won't render if SocialRibbonControl is deactivated.

If you want the links to appear, but you don't want the SocialRibbonControl feature activated, you could create a delegate control that replaces this guy,

```
<Control Id="GlobalSiteLink2" Sequence="100" ControlSrc="~/_controltemplates/socialdata.ascx" />
<Control Id="GlobalSiteLink2-mini" Sequence="100"
    ControlClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SocialNavigationControl"
    ControlAssembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

If you put that in an element file, and deploy it as a Farm Feature, the links will appear even if you have SocialRibbonControl deactivated.